# Finder "Show Icon Preview" for certain filetypes?

Tags: macos, finder, preview, icon, file

In OSX (Yosemite) I've figured out how to switch between showing a file as an icon or as a preview in Finder.  I can go to *Finder > View > Show View Options* and then toggle the *Show icon preview* checkbox.

What I'm wondering is if there is some way to show the preview for certain file types but not for others.  Basically, I want to see the preview if it is an image file, but just see the file type icon for everything else (.doc(x), .pdf, .txt, etc.).

Is there a way to do this, or is it strictly one way or the other?

Answer (score 1):

It's really one way or the other as you have speculated.  Don't worry, it really shouldn't slow things down having these otherwise convenient little thumbnails created for everything you have.